# JSSOR Navigation Arrows Not Working

Tags: razor, navigation, slider, jssor

My slider is not working for some reason, and I cannot figure it out. Here's the code:

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: relative; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 700px; height: 400px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp2.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp3.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
</div>

<!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 500px; float:left; margin-left: 135px;">
        </span>
<!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 500px; float:left; margin-left: 910px;">
        </span>
<!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
```

Comment: **How** is it not working? What happens?

Comment: The arrows just don't work when I click on them. They are there and the slide show works when you click and drag but the arrows just don't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please place the 2 arrows inside 'slider1_container'.

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: relative; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 700px; height: 400px;">
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp1.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp2.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img u="image" src="@appRoot/images/Slider/camp3.jpg" /></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 500px; float:left; margin-left: 135px;"></span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="width: 55px; height: 55px; top: 500px; float:left; margin-left: 910px;"></span>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->

</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did this but then the arrows don't even appear.